# delete a row in table A based on condition when row inserted in table A

Tags: sql

I have two tables `roombooking` and `vacantrooms`.

Table `vacantrooms` is supposed to list only the vacant rooms. Booking and vacating details goes into the `roombooking` table.

```
select * from roombooking;

roomnum  cname   bdate       numamale  numafemale  numcmale  numcfemale  totalmembers  bstatus  vdate       vstatus    bnum  
-------  ------  ----------  --------  ----------  --------  ----------  ------------  -------  ----------  -------  --------
    108  VJ      2022-01-06         1           2         0           2             5  Booked   (NULL)      (NULL)          1
    120  Vimal   2022-01-08         1           3         0           0             4  Booked   (NULL)      Vacated         2
    121  Kiran   2022-01-08         1           1         1           0             3  Booked   2022-01-10  Vacated         3
    125  DLK     2022-01-08         3           4         0           0             7  Booked   (NULL)      Vacated         5
    130  DLK     2022-01-10         3           4         0           0             7  Booked   (NULL)      Vacated         6
    133  VJ      2022-01-10         3           4         1           1             9  Booked   2020-01-12  Vacated         7
```

When a room is booked then the corresponding room num if listed in `vacantrooms` should be deleted.

When a booked is vacated then the corresponding room num should be listed. No duplicate entries

Below are the triggers I have created:

To remove the duplicate entry:

```
CREATE TRIGGER occupiedrooms_delete 
AFTER UPDATE ON roombooking 
FOR EACH ROW 

    DELETE t1 FROM vacantrooms t1 
    INNER JOIN vacantrooms t2 
    WHERE t1.id < t2.id AND t1.roomnum = t2.roomnum;
```

To update the room number when updated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER vacatedrooms_insert 
AFTER UPDATE ON roombooking 
FOR EACH ROW 

    INSERT INTO vacantrooms (roomnum, vdate, vstatus) 
        SELECT roomnum, vdate, vstatus 
        FROM roombooking 
        WHERE vstatus = 'Vacated' AND bstatus = 'Booked';
```

But when a new row is inserted like a row listed in `vacantrooms` is booked then I'm not able to delete it from `vacantrooms`.

Below trigger is not working not sure what is wrong or how to make it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_occupied_room 
AFTER INSERT ON roombooking 
FOR EACH ROW 
    DELETE t1 
    FROM vacantrooms t2 
    INNER JOIN roombookings t2 
    WHERE t2.roomnum = t1.roomnum 
      AND t2.bstatus = 'Booked' 
      AND t2.vstatus = NULL;
```

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are really using.

Comment: Also whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. It helps easily distinguish specific code blocks, and sections, and also makes finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: Do you mean nothing is deleted? or do you mean you get an error?

Comment: *If* you are using SQL Server, the fact that you don't reference the `inserted` pseudo tables in the `AFTER INSERT` and neither the `deleted` or `inserted` pseudo tables is also a sign of a flaw.

Comment: Why do you even have a table `vacantrooms`? You don't need it and you shouldn't have it. If you need a list of vacant rooms *in a certain period in time* join the rooms table and `roombooking` appropriately.